# map physical storage to two heaps with mmap()

Tags: c, unix, posix

I'm trying to map the same chunk of 1MB memory to two heaps using mmap:

```
int* pointer_to_physical = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_ELEMENTS_ARRAY);

//Map chunk of 1MB memory to private address space
first_Heap = mmap (pointer_to_physical, sizeof(int) * NUM_ELEMENTS_ARRAY, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); 
second_Heap = mmap (pointer_to_physical, sizeof(int) * NUM_ELEMENTS_ARRAY, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

If I'm correct they point to the same physical memory but they are positioned on different addresses of the private address space.

I want to when we write to a heap than the physical memory is written and then the second heap will have automatically the value:

```
first_heap[0]=1980;
printf("second_heap should have the same value: %d",second_heap);
```

Output:

```
second_heap should have the same value: 0
```

What should I change in order to be 1980?

Comment: Suggest you re-read the `mmap` man page. The first paramter (`addr`) is not a "source" address for the mapping. That is, it doesn't tell `mmap` where the memory comes from for the mapping. It tells `mmap` to try and place the mapping at that address (ie, a "target" address). And the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag results in new memory being allocated, which makes the `malloc` redundant (and creates memory leaks).

Comment: Is there any way to map two times the exact memory chunk?

Comment: What is wrong with `first_heap = malloc(size); second_heap = first_heap;`? If that is not what you want please clarify what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I want two different heaps that maps the same memory chunk, but I want them to be somehow different that I can change the protection of one heap without affecting the other and also I want that both heaps have the same values

Comment: You can't easily do it with `malloc` memory. One way to do something like this is with [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html). Call `shm_open` to get a piece of shared memory. Then `ftruncate` to size it. And finally `mmap` to map it with the attributes you want. Give it a go. If you can't get it working then post your code and explain what difficulty you have.